# When is 行く pronounced as いく, and when is it ゆく?

Tags: pronunciation

Are there any rules or guidelines as to when to pronounce 行く as いく or ゆく?

I looked it up on [jisho.org](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F&eng=&dict=edict), and the two pronunciations have the exact same definition. I tend to hear ゆく more often in songs, but that is just anecdotal.

Comment: I've always wondered why lyrics often say `いく` in kana even when the singer clearly sings `ゆく`...

Comment: ゆく is for songs and train destinations.

Comment: I'm not confident enough to put this as an answer, but 行く is pretty much *always* いく, except for specific exceptions. In addition to train destinations and songs, there's 行方不明{ゆくえふめい}, for example.

Comment: Something interesting I've seen.  `ゆく` and `いく` are considered a distinct separate readings of `行く`, and not just some kind of dialectical pronunciation or euphonic change (音便).  When I lived in Japan, I was watching one of those "variety" shows.  They were talking about the kanji(s) with the most readings (the most being `生` I believe).  Anyway, the contestants had to collectively produce all the readings for each one.  When doing `行`, they left out `ゆく` and were surprised to learn that `いく` and `ゆく` were in fact different.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The explanation in [デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/225173/meaning/m0u/) is:

> 「いく」の語形も上代からみられ、平安時代以降は「ゆく」と併用される。「ゆく」「いく」はほとんど意味は同じであるが、古くは「ゆく」のほうがより広く使われ、特に訓点資料・和歌（「生く」との掛け詞の場合を除き）では、ほとんどすべてが「ゆく」である。現在では「ゆく」に比べて「いく」のほうが話し言葉的な感じをもち、したがって、「過ぎ行く」「散り行く」など、文章語的な語の場合には「ゆく」となるのが普通である。なお、「ゆきて」のイ音便形「ゆいて」も用いられたが、現在は一般的でなく、促音便形は「ゆく」のほうは用いられず、「いく」を用いて「いって」「いった」となる。

My translation / synopsis is as follows:

いく has been seen from ancient times but from the Heian period both have been in use.  いく has almost exactly the same meaning as ゆく but in olden times, ゆく was used more widely: Putting the use of double entendres and word play based on 生く aside, then the use of 行く in Japanese poetry (waka/tanka) or symbolism can almost always read as ゆく.  As a result, when expressions such as 「過ぎ行く」「散り行く」 are used stylistically in written language they are normally read as ゆく. However forms such as ゆきて have stopped being used in favour of forms derived from いく such as いって and いった.

Answer (score 0):

They both mean the same of course, and there is plenty of info you can find explaining that ゆく is an older version. In addition, I have found that while いく tends to be a somewhat casual version of ゆく. いく is *easier* to pronounce than ゆく. Also, FWIW, I think いく is used more often than ゆく in conversation.

Comment: 「ゆく tends to be a more informal version of いく」>>>逆だと思います。「ゆく is also easier to pronounce than いく」>>>逆だと思います。「ゆく is used more often than いく in conversation」>>>逆だと思います。「ゆく」と「いく」を取り違えられたんですかね・・・？

Comment: I meant the opposite!

Comment: あ、やっぱり？ｗｗｗ・・・・・