# Iki versus Yuki meaning "bound for"

Tags: kanji, readings

Can we read ー行き as "iki" talking about trains bound for some stations?

For example,

> この列車は東京行きです。

[Here](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%9D%B1%E4%BA%AC%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8D) they say we should read it as "yuki."

[Here](https://jisho.org/search/bound%20for) I see that "iki" is used to mean "bound for". But the example sentence is not about a station.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is 行く pronounced as いく, and when is it ゆく?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12440/when-is-%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%8f-pronounced-as-%e3%81%84%e3%81%8f-and-when-is-it-%e3%82%86%e3%81%8f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think both options are perfectly fine, and I do not even remember which is more common after using Japanese buses and trains thousands of times. But maybe いき is a little bit safer according to other opinions on the net.